# Is there a way to write fast nested loops in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, nested-loops

I wrote a function that takes a set of multiple variables and matches it to a list of dataframes (which contains 5572 rows with presence and absence of those variables), later calculating a distance matrix.

In other words, I have a list with 25 presence/absence vectors (filled with 0s and ONE 1) and a list of 25 dataframes (also filled with 0s and 1s). Vectors and dataframes are in iterable order, meaning veclist[0] matches column number in PAM[0] and so on. The function has a nested loop, with the outer loop running the dataframes in order and the inner loop running the rows (finds in which row the variables occur in the dataframe for all 25 variables and gives it a value)

To illustrate it better I recreated a short version of my data below.

The list of vectors looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

A = np.random.randint(1, size=6).reshape(1, 6)
B = np.random.randint(1, size=11).reshape(1, 11)
A[:,2]=1
B[:,7]=1
vec1 = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=["a","b","c","d","e","f"])
vec2 = pd.DataFrame(B, columns=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k"])
veclist=[vec1,vec2]
print(veclist[0])
```

and the list of dataframes looks like this:

```
A2 = np.random.randint(2, size=600).reshape(100,6)
B2 = np.random.randint(2, size=1100).reshape(100,11)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(A2, columns=["a","b","c","d","e","f"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(B2, columns=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k"])
dflist=[df1,df2]
print(dflist[0])
```

This is the code for the function I wrote.

```
def find_distance(veclist,dflist):
    ncol=len(dflist)
    nrow=dflist[0].shape[0]
    distance=np.zeros((nrow,ncol))
    for k in range(ncol):
        pres=np.where(veclist[k]==1) #getting matching column (where the vector matches the header)
        PAM=dflist[k]
        for m in range(nrow):
            if (veclist[k].iloc[pres]==1).bool() & (PAM.iloc[m,pres[1]]==1).bool():
                a = 2
            else:
                a = 0

            if (veclist[k].iloc[pres]==1).bool() & (PAM.iloc[m,pres[1]]==0).bool():
                b = 1
            else:
                b = 0

            if (veclist[k].iloc[pres]==0).bool() & (PAM.iloc[m,pres[1]]==1).bool():
                c = 1
            else:
                c = 0

        d = (2 * a)/(2 * a + b + c)
        d = math.sqrt(1-d)
        distance[m,k]=d
    return distance
```

This function works: it does everything I need it to do. However, it is *very* slow. With my real data, it is taking up to a minute to run the inner loop. I am more familiar with R, where this same function runs in seconds. So why is this function taking up to 25 minutes to run in python?

**What did I do wrong?**

I am guessing that the problem is the code needs to be more pythonic. I am slowly migrating from R to python, and still have some difficulties. For example, I don't know how to do away with the nested loop and use Numpy, since everything needs to be perfectly matched and saved. Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

I am using python 3.7 and the spyder IDE.

Comment: Are you certain your nested loop is what is causing your performance issues? I would suggest attaching some type of timer decorator to your function just to be sure.

Comment: I am certain is the nested loop. I did not use a timer, but this function is part of another bigger function and in the first trials I had prints all over the code. This nested loop is the problem.